# Select part of PATH variable in bash_profile and insert it into another file

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Fairly new to anything Linux. I have a path variable in my users' bash profile that we'd like to utilize from some of our scripts on the server.

The part of the script that I'm changing is as follows

```
if [[ ${PATH} =~ .*scripts/new.* ]]; then
   export BASE_PATH=/data/scripts/new:/data/scripts:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/mssql-tools/bin:/home/${USER}/bin
else
   export BASE_PATH=/data/scripts:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/mssql-tools/bin:/home/${USER}/bin
```

I plan to remove the `/home/${USER}/bin` piece, and instead, I'd like to select part of the PATH variables from the user's .bash_profile and have it appended

In the bash_profile, an example of the PATH variable is

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$HOME/bin/scaffold.d
```

I'd like to select everything after the fist colon like so

```
$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$HOME/bin/scaffold.d
```

And then have it be able to pull that into the script, something similar to

```
if [[ ${PATH} =~ .*scripts/new.* ]]; then
   export BASE_PATH=/data/scripts/new:/data/scripts:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/mssql-tools/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$HOME/bin/scaffold.d
else
   export BASE_PATH=/data/scripts:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/mssql-tools/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$HOME/bin/scaffold.d
```

I believe using grep would work here but I'm not quite sure how to implement it.

Comment: `PATH_PART=$(grep ^PATH= bashrc_profile | sed -e "s/^[^:]*://")`

Comment: This works great for my own bash profile, but it seems that when running it against another user who has a bit more content to theirs, it returns the full `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$HOME/bin/scaffold.d`. Could you clarify what your comment does exactly?

Comment: The `grep` command selects only lines starting with `PATH=`.  The `sed` command removes the start of the line up to and including the first colon.  If there are corner cases, (like multiple `PATH=` lines) you'll need to debug them by checking the `grep` and `sed` commands individually.  You probably need to read tutorials or man pages on these commands.